# I need either a confirmation or a refutation regarding the following theory of mine about the pattern"“noun phrase + of + possessive pronoun”

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis, pronouns, possessives

I've been thinking a lot about this matter, and this is what I came up with as a rather complicated yet seemingly airtight rule regarding when not to use the aforementioned pattern. It goes like this:

• When talking about *people* and generally *living things*, the verb "to be" can come before the noun phrase, as in:

"He is a friend of mine"

"She was a cousin of hers"

"That is a dog of the queen's"

---

• However, when talking about *objects* and *tangibles*, the verb "to be" doesn't usually come before the noun phrase. A false sentence to corroborate this would be "this is a car of mine". Instead, we generally use the verb after the possessive pronoun, as in:

"That car of yours was a beauty"

"This ugly sofa of his takes up so much room in the house"

---

• On the other hand, when talking about *intangibles*, the use of the verb "to be" before the noun phrase is completely OK, as in:

"That is a bad habit of yours"

"This is a trick of mine to get these things open"

Although in some cases this may sound a bit unusual and uncommon (yet, perfectly grammatical), as in:

"That is a great personality of yours"

---

Now, have I gone crazy or does what I said make sense? Can you make an example that would refute this (perhaps one in which a tangible can be used after the verb "to be" and before the possessive pronoun)?

P.S. I deleted a previous post of mine similar (yet with crucial differences) to this one in order to avoid duplication. This is a much more thorough description of what's been bothering me for a week now.

Comment: You’ve crafted examples that can’t be reversed for reasons other than “NP of POSS” being present. For example: “....is him.”, “A beauty was...”, “....is this.” are all unnatural sounding even with different synonymous subjects/objects.

Comment: 'She was a cousin of hers' sounds unusual to unnatural. 'A temperature of mine last week was alarmingly high' is, I'd say, unacceptable. Sometimes, the 'double possessive' as it is known is just unacceptable.

Comment: I have serious misgivings about *That is a great personality of yours*. One of the big differences between *an X of mine* and *my X* is that the former strongly implies ***I have other X's besides this one***. So assuming the person whose personality you're praising isn't seriously two-faced, I think it would be better to say ***Yours is a great personality***.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Apropos which, do you not agree that IF prior context had established that temperature readouts (possibly regular, recent, and/or from several people) were the primary focus of the conversation, it *could* be perfectly natural to refer to *a temperature of mine last week*?

Comment: @FumbleFingers that's what I thought at first, but someone here ( BoldBen) said it is perfectly grammatical. Also, are you suggesting IF we have more than one car, we can say "this is a car of mine"?

Comment: @Askeladd: Don't overplay the "grammatical" aspect. This isn't really a matter of grammar at all - it's about ***idiomacy***. But even though it's perfectly grammatical, I don't think many native speakers would approve of, say, *I'd like you to meet a mother of mine.*

Comment: ... And 'This little house of mine' is a far bigger hit than 'this little cottage of mine' [[Google 5grams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=this+little+house+of+mine%2Cthis+little+cottage+of+mine&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthis%20little%20house%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cthis%20little%20house%20of%20mine%3B%2Cc0)]